# Add extra fee only for specific product type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add an extra percentage fee to the cart subtotal for specific product type only.
In my shop, there are simple, variant and auction products. What I would like to do is to apply a percentage fee of 18.6% in the cart only on the subtotal of the auction products.
I have the code to distinguish the action products and the code to apply the fee into the cart total (not subtotal). How can I combine those?

Code for distinguish action products:

```
global $woocommerce, $product, $post;
if(!(method_exists( $product, 'get_type') && $product->get_type() == 'auction')){
return;
}
```

Code for adding the percentage fee into the cart total

```
/** ADD EXTRA FEES ON CHECKOUT */
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function() {
if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
return;
}
$percentage = 0.186;
$percentage_fee = (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total()) * $percentage;
WC()->cart->add_fee(__('[:en]Extra fee[:el]Προμήθεια[:]', 'txtdomain'), $percentage_fee);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use this plugin for it
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-conditional-product-fees-for-checkout/

Comment: This plugin and all similar plugins check if a product satisfies the condition and applies the extra fee to the cart total and not to the subtotal of the products of the specific type. That is my problem.....

Comment: I think there is no option to add fees to subtotal, you have to add fees to cart totals

Answer (score 0):

OK after some research I was able to add a special fee on checkout only for products of specific category and not to all of the products in the cart. Here is the code I am using:

```
/** ADD EXTRA FEE ON CHECKOUT ON AUCTIONS PRODUCTS ONLY */
function add_fee_surcharge( $cart_object ) {
global $woocommerce;
$specialfeecat = 306; // category id for the special fee
$spfee = 0.00; // initialize special fee
$spfeeperprod = 0.186; //special fee per product

foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
  $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart
  $quantiy = $value['quantity']; //get quantity from cart
  $itmprice = $value['data']->price; //get product price
  $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' ); //get taxonomy of the products
  if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $catid = $term->term_id;
          $pcats = get_ancestors($catid, 'product_cat');
          $parentcats = array_unique($pcats);
          if (in_array($specialfeecat, $parentcats)) { 
            $spfee = $spfee + $itmprice * $quantiy * $spfeeperprod;
            break;
          }
      }
  endif;  
}
  if($spfee > 0 ) {
  $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( '[:en]Extra fee[:el]Προμήθεια[:]', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
  }
 }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_fee_surcharge' );
```

The above code adds a fee of 18.6% for the products that belong to category ID 306!